# Изменение строки label во время анимации

Tags: python, pyqt5

как в `QPropertyAnimation` можно изменить строку label в определённом моменте.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Тест')

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Надпись")
        self.label.move(200, 200)

        self.animation()

    def animation(self):
        self.animation_group = QSequentialAnimationGroup()

        # центр --> низ
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"pos")
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(200, 200))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(200, 350))
        self.anim.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation_group.addAnimation(self.anim)

        # верх --> центр
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"pos")
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(200, 50))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(200, 200))
        self.anim.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation_group.addAnimation(self.anim)

        self.animation_group.setLoopCount(3)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.animation_group.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Допустим мне нужно чтобы label, каждый раз когда оказывался наверху, менял свой текст на другой. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно отследить момент смены текущей анимации (при этом QPropertyAnimation издает сигнал currentAnimationChanged)

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 300, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Тест')

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Надпись")
        self.label.move(200, 200)
        self.animation()

    def animation(self):
        self.colors = ['#0000FF', '#00FF00', '#FF0000', '#FF0000']
        self.animation_group = QSequentialAnimationGroup()

        # центр --> низ
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"pos")
        self.anim.setStartValue(QPoint(200, 200))
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(200, 350))
        self.anim.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation_group.addAnimation(self.anim)

        # верх --> центр
        self.anim2 = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"pos")
        self.anim2.setStartValue(QPoint(200, 50))
        self.anim2.setEndValue(QPoint(200, 200))
        self.anim2.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation_group.addAnimation(self.anim2)

        self.animation_group.setLoopCount(3)
        self.animation_group.currentAnimationChanged.connect(self.changeColor)


    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.animation_group.start()
    def changeColor(self,anim):
        if anim == self.anim2:
            c = self.colors.pop(0)
            self.colors.append(c)
            self.label.setStyleSheet(f'color: {c}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает в точности как надо